# finding the number of grey levels

Tags: python, image, image-processing

```
[[7 7 7 6 6 6 7  8
  6 6 7 7 6 7 7  8
  6 7 7 7 7 7 8  8
  6 7 7 7 7 7 7  7 
  6 7 7 7 6 6 6  6
  6 7 7 6 6 6 6  6
  6 7 7 7 7 7 8  9
  7 8 8 8 8 9 10 11]]
```

i am doing some image processing and this is a 8x8 gray scale array. I am trying to find the number of grey levels in this array. Is there any particular function or a simple method to find the same using python.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use numpy or other packages? Or only plain python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @chris who posted an excellent answer using plain Python:

Using [numpy.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get all gray levels:

```
>>> np.unique(gray[0])
array([6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

and you can even return the indices of the original array that gave the unique values!

Example from the Docs:

```
>>> a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'])
>>> u, indices = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
>>> u
array(['a', 'b', 'c'],
       dtype='|S1')
>>> indices
array([0, 1, 3])
>>> a[indices]
array(['a', 'b', 'c'],
       dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
len(set(gray[0])) # gray = [[gray levels]]
```

Create a set that stores unique values from the list and then count the elements.

Comment: This will be easier if am doing it for one single array. But if there are a number of arrays say (1000)will this method be a better solution?

Comment: you could combine that with some sort of lazy list expression (so as not to load all in RAM at once), but I'm sure numpy is probably quicker as its more optimised.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = np.array([[7,7,7,6,6,6,7,8
... ,6,6,7,7,6,7,7,8
... ,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8
... ,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
... ,6,7,7,7,6,6,6,6
... ,6,7,7,6,6,6,6,6
... ,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,9
... ,7,8,8,8,8,9,1,0,11]])
>>> a
array([[ 7,  7,  7,  6,  6,  6,  7,  8,  6,  6,  7,  7,  6,  7,  7,  8,  6,
         7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  6,  7,
         7,  7,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,
         7,  7,  7,  8,  9,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  1,  0, 11]])
>>> np.unique(a)
array([ 0,  1,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11])
>>> np.unique(a).shape[0]
7
```